# What videos should everyone watch?

Tags: soft-question, specific-reference

Similar to this [cstheory question](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/1198/what-videos-should-everybody-watch) "What videos should everyone watch?" What conferences, workshops or lectures have recordings that researchers in theoretical physics should watch?

Comment: You may want to expand the question with a bit more explanation as in the cstheory question. I've marked this CW.

Comment: -1 unless with a longer description (I second Joe's comment).

Answer (score 6):

I have no doubt about:

Richard Feynman, [The pleasure of finding things out](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bgaw9qe7DEE).

Answer (score 4):

Leonard Susskind has multiple series of lectures online on Youtube.

http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLB64419BFD176F2FD

- Special Relativity
- Quantum Mechanics
- General Theory of Relativity
- Cosmology
- Statistical Mechanics
- Particle Physics
- Quantum Entanglement

Comment: There are additional courses from Lenny Susskind about SUSY: http://itunes.apple.com/us/itunes-u/supersymmetry-grand-unification/id384233338 , string and M-theory: http://www.youtube.com/view_play_list?p=202191442DB1B300 , and topics in string theory: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NZ-ElsvYKyo&feature=relmfu